# how to use fql query

Tags: facebook-fql

i am new at facebook application development i want to know how fql query works i used it in my application but i want to know where fql query results are displayed or how they can be displayed if you can't explain plz send me the link because the official documentation didn't helped me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect to FB using the PHP SDK. (available [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/))

> ```
> ini_set('display_errors',1);
> error_reporting(E_ALL);
> require_once 'library/facebook/src/facebook.php';
> ```

1. Check if the user has logged in to FB

> ```
> $facebook = new Facebook(array(
> 'appId'  => 'YOUR API ID',    
> 'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET',   
> 'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
> ));
> ```

1. FQL

   ```
   try {
         $me = $facebook->api('/me');

         $currentPage=1;
         $currentPost=1;
         $currentDate="";

         $list="";
         $arrDate=array();

         $fql    =   "YOUR FQL STATEMENT HERE";
         $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
         );
         $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);//Here you have your FQL result set

         foreach($fqlResult as $row){
         //Do something to the result

         }

       } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
         error_log($e);
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook Graph Explorer
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
And select under the Access token field, "FQL query".
Now you can try FQL queries and see the result of them.